# Override CSS with fewer declarations

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I'm trying to override the css from bootstrap. 
I going to design the navbar without color.

```
.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#f2f2f2));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
}
```

with

```
.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;

}
```

I delete background color replacing it in the bootstrap .css.

Is it possible to just override it with another value?

Answer (score 7):

Short Answer: **YES**

Long Answer Follows

The way CSS works is called specificity. There's is an order in which styles are applied to an element. Think of it as 4 separate numbers with the default value of each being 0. So 0,0,0,0 is the default

- The first number represents inline styles
  e.g., `<span style="color: red">I'm Red</span>`
- The second number represents IDs
  e.g., `#IdSelector`
- The third number represents classes
  e.g., `.ClassSelector`
- The fourth number represents element and pseudo selectors
  e.g., `div` and `:first-child`

These rules are applied in the order of internal style sheet first, external stylesheet second. If there's a rule defined ANYWHERE that applies to your element and you don't override it with a selector that has a higher specificity, then it will stay the same.

The following will override

```
.navbar-inner {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Going back to specificity.

If your element is `<div id="mainNav" class="navbar-inner"></div>`

```
#mainNav {
    background-image: none;
}
.navbar-inner {
    background-image: url(img.png);
}
```

Then the image will be set to none. The ID selector has a specificity of 0,1,0,0 and the class sector has a specificity of 0,0,1,0.

Even if you added 11 classes the ID would still win, the specificity in that case would be 0,0,11,0

There is one last number, a hidden number. so 0,0,0,0,0 The one in front represents `!important`, which can be added after any style declaration to make it apply no matter what. If you have two conflicting declarations which have `!important` listed, it falls back to the order of inline vs. embedded vs. external. Generally you should avoid !important at most costs, except where it absolutely makes sense.

## !important example that makes sense.

```
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, you should add about inline styles and !important;

Comment: I already had the bit about inline styles, but I elaborated on !important;